# Python requests POST returns 400 instead 200

Tags: python-requests

I'm expecting `200` though `400` get's returned.

Does one see what I'm doing wrong in my request?

Code:

```
import   requests
import   json
import   lxml.html
from     lxml.cssselect   import   CSSSelector
from     lxml.etree       import   fromstring

SELECTOR  = CSSSelector('[type=hidden]')
BASE_URL  = 'https://www.bonuscard.ch/myos/en/login'
LOGIN_URL = BASE_URL+'1.IFormSubmitListener-homePanel-loginPanel-loginForm'
# headers copied from chromium (returns 200)
headers   = {
        "Accept"                    : "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Encoding"           : "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language"           : "en,de;q=0.9",
        "Cache-Control"             : "no-cache",
        "Connection"                : "keep-alive",
        "Content-Length"            : "151",
        "Content-Type"              : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "DNT"                       : "1",
        "Host"                      : "www.bonuscard.ch",
        "Origin"                    : "https: //www.bonuscard.ch",
        "Pragma"                    : "no-cache",
        "Referer"                   : "https: //www.bonuscard.ch/myos/en/login",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" : "1",
        "User-Agent"                : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"
        }
with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.get(BASE_URL)
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(response.content)
    keyOnly_token = [e.get('id') for e in SELECTOR(tree)][0]
    payload = {
            keyOnly_token:"",
            "userName-border:userName-border_body:userName ": "jon@doe.com",
            "password-border:password-border_body:password ": "123",
            "login                                         ": ""
            }
    response = session.post(LOGIN_URL,headers=headers,data=payload)
    # Returns 400
    print(response)
```

These changes displayed no difference either:

- POST without `headers`
- POST with `json=payload` instead of `data=payload`

Comment: does a `curl` request produce the same `400` output?

Comment: @IvanVinogradov `curl` returns `200` (copied POST request from chromium 'copy as curl' and requested it with postman)

Comment: can you add this `curl` request to the question

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ivan's direction I found this *curl* to *requests* converter which was the solution https://curl.trillworks.com/#